# gulp - how to stop or cancel taks from running

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I have a gulp browser sync to start server and reload when change is made. My problem is when Im done with watching files and reloading browser, I dont know how to stop the task from running? Nothing happens when i press enter. Im not good at cmd, Windows user

[image: gulp screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK?